# BeforeDoubleClick Event with multiple ranges

Tags: vba, events, inputbox

Good afternoon,

I am trying to utilize the `BeforeDoubleClick` event within a worksheet that calls an input box for column `L` that prompts users to input their ID and another call for an input box that prompts users to enter the name of a team member that is giving a tour in column `J`.  The code I had worked fine when it was just one event within column `L`, but the addition of the inputbox within column `J` keeps returning the `"compile error: Argument not optional"`.  My current code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

   On Error Resume Next
   enterUserName Target
   GuideName Target

End Sub

Sub enterUserName(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim x As Range, Y As Range

Set x = Target
Set Y = Range("L3:L300")

If Intersect(x, Y) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Cancel = True
        t.Offset(0, 0).Value = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter your User ID.")
End Sub

Sub GuideName(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim t As Range, B As Range

Set t = Target
Set B = Range("J3:J300")

If Intersect(t, B) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Cancel = True
t.Offset(0, 0).Value = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter ONLY the first name of the tour guide.")

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: You're not passing the `Cancel` parameter into your two sub-procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Matt -

After some further research and troubleshooting, the code is working for both events utilizing the BeforeDoubleClick event. The most helpful information came from Tushar Mehta's website: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1021_multiple_tasks_in_an_event_procedure.htm
I made minimal changes to the last example on the website, and changed my original sub to the following (and everything is working like I had hoped):

```
Private Sub GoBeforeDoubleClick1(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim t As Range, B As Range
Set t = Target
Set B = Range("L3:L300")
If Intersect(t, B) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
Else: t.Offset(0, 0).Value = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter your User ID.")
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub

Private Sub GoBeforeDoubleClick2(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim x As Range, Y As Range
Set x = Target
Set Y = Range("J3:J300")
If Intersect(x, Y) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
Else: x.Offset(0, 0).Value = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter ONLY the first name of the tour guide.")
Exit Sub
End If
Cancel = True
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
GoBeforeDoubleClick1 Target, Cancel
GoBeforeDoubleClick2 Target, Cancel
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```